# How to compress a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

With tar, I tried to compress a repository in a chroot environment with ssh, but it failed as it just compressed the symbolic link itself.

How can I compress its content?

```
-bash-3.00$ ls -ail
1263583 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root       18 Apr 18  2008 mainwebsite_html -> ../../var/www/html

-bash-3.00$ tar -cjvf archive.tar.bz2 mainwebsite_html

-bash-3.00$ ls -ail
7509101 -rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1  136 Feb 22 08:57 archive.tar.bz2
1263583 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root       18 Apr 18  2008 mainwebsite_html -> ../../var/www/html
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the `tar(1)` man page:

> ```
>   -h, --dereference
>           follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to
> ```

Answer (score 23):

Take care of placing the "h" option in the correct place. In your example:

```
tar -cjvf archive.tar.bz2 mainwebsite_html
```

should be

```
tar -chjvf archive.tar.bz2 mainwebsite_html
```

Comment: Good call; it's so easy to forget that -f actually takes an argument ;)